# How do I set an action for the root outline of a PDF

Tags: itext

How do I set an action on the root Outline for a PDF?

I know I can do this on a kid of the root:

```
newOutline = new PdfOutline (rootOutline, PdfAction.GotoLocalPage ("1", false), rootNode.DivisionLabel, true);
```

But how to I do the same thing for the root?

In that I can not set the root outline (its readonly), and I can not set an action for it either. I get started like this:

```
PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader (rs);  
int pageCount = inputPdf.NumberOfPages;  
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper (inputPdf, ws);  
PdfWriter writer = stamper.Writer;  
writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines;  
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;  
PdfOutline rootOutline = cb.RootOutline;
```

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

I could never get the PdfWriter returned by stamper.writer to work. I had to change my method such that it uses an independent PdfReader and PdfWriter pair, where I can copy the pages from the input PDF to output PDF while adding the needed local destinations and outlines. Grrr very frustrating working with iTextSharp...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can set an action for the root Outline. When would it trigger?  The root is just a container for any other outlines.

If you want to always Go To Page 1 when the document opens, then there are other ways of doing that.